# how to name java package for org.test.toolkit.database.resultsethandle;

Tags: java, package

I have one java package for resultset handle, So I create the package named resultsethandle.
the puzzle is that I know all package names should be lower case. but you can see that the resultsethandle seems ugly. So how can I solve the puzzle? I try to use another short name but it is only just the meaning for resultset handle.

So can someone help me ? should the package always be lower case?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it may initially look odd, the standard would be to leave it in all lowercase.

Comment: what a pity? any other solutions exist?

Answer (score 0):

The standard would be to leave it in lowercase. However, it sounds like a class name as it sounds very specific. "A ResultSet handle class". Typically packages are used to group classes together that are for a specific type of work. Browsing the java packages may give you   more understanding of package names. For example, java.io - A package for input/output classes, interfaces etc. java.net - A package for network classes.

But, in the end, a package is just a name that makes sense in your situation.

Comment: it includes all classes about resultset handle, So can I change the package name from resultsethandle to resultset? does it make sence?